# Is there a way to download actual file from git lfs pointers?

Tags: linux, git, git-lfs

I have a git repository in which I have `git-lfs` pointers for some large files. If one clones the repository he can download the actual file using `git lfs pull`.

But if someone downloads repository working directory, it's not a git repository  so `git lfs pull` won't work.

Is it possible to get the large files without cloning the repository?

Also `git lfs pull` downloads every `big-file` for which there is a `git-lfs` pointer. Is there a way to download only a particular file among these big files and keep the rest as `text-pointers`?

Comment: When you say "downloads the repository", you mean "downloads the working folder but doesn't have the git repository metadata"?

Comment: @EdwardThomson Exactly

Comment: It's been a while. Did you find an answer to your questions? I would be interested especially in the second one, as it could offer functionality such as reducing storage space locally.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this is part of the concept of Git. Git is made for versioning, so it makes sense that after `git lsf pull` one gets a *consistent* state without worrying if all the necessary LFS files have been downloaded or not.

Hence I do not think that `git` commands can download a specific LFS file (although lurking in the source code might prove me wrong).

However the Git provider that you use *should* provide a way to download such files singularly via their GUI.
For example either GitHub and GitLab have a "Download" button to fetch from LFS storage:

- GitHub: https://github.com/seeraven/lfs-example/blob/main/included/second.png
- GitLab: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-examples/lfs/-/blob/master/Cat_poster_1.jpg (the <kbd>↧</kbd> aside of *"Open in Web IDE"* button.

I suppose other hosting services like BitBucket.org and similar also provide a button to download single files (LFS and not).